# Replace "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia" with "canvas.captureStream"

Tags: javascript, canvas, webrtc, getusermedia, red5pro

I'm using Red5pro html SDK to create a peer to peer connection between a server and a client, video and audio chat work like a charm with **getUserMedia()**.
The problem is, I want to stream from a DOM element(Canvas), not from user's camera, using **captureStream()**.

Red5Pro has method called "*OnGetUserMedia*" with the following instructions:

> The onGetUserMedia method - when defined on the configuration provide to a WebRTC-based Publisher - will override the internal call to getUserMedia in the Red5 Pro HTML SDK.

> You can provide your own logic on how getUserMedia is invoked and a Media Stream attained by setting the onGetUserMedia attribute to a method that conforms to the following guidelines:

> No input arguments are provided to onGetUserMedia.
> It is expected that a Promise object is returned.
> A MediaStream object must be provided in the resolve of the Promise.

When I did a research and asked the Red5pro Support team, they said

> Inside of the promise returned, you can derive a MediaStream from captureStream.

Ref: [Red5Pro Documentation](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/streaming/publisher.html#webrtc)

I just don't have a clue what to do, or what to change.

here's a sample of the *onGetUserMedia* Method:

```js
{
  host: "localhost",
  protocol: 8083,
  port: 8081,
  streamName: "mystream",
  iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302" }],
  onGetUserMedia: function () {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: {
        width: {
          max: 1920,
          ideal: 1280,
          min: 640,
        },
        width: {
          max: 1080,
          ideal: 720,
          min: 360,
        },
      },
    });
  },
};
```

Any Help?

Comment: `onGetUserMedia:()=>Promise.resolve(canvas.captureStream(30)),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have been asked to do is to set the `onGetUserMedia` property to a function that does return a Promise, itself resolving to a MediaStream.

This is probably because they've built their API with the *correct* assumption that most MediaStreams their user will have is one coming from *mediaDevices.getUserMedia* method, and this method does return such a Promise that do resolve to a MediaStream.

In order to comply with their code, you have to wrap your own MediaStream in such a Promise.
Indeed, `HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream` is synchronous and returns directly the MediaStream, without a Promise wrapper.

So to do this, you just need to create a function that will wrap your MediaStream in a Promise, and this can be done by the [*Promise.resolve*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) method:

```
{
  [...]
  iceServers: [{urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'}],
  onGetUserMedia: () => Promise.resolve(canvas.captureStream(frameRate))
}
```

---

Ps:
`() =>` syntax is ES6 [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), widely supported by browsers that do support *HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream*.